# BizTalk: How to set output filename in SendPort to represent current DateTime

Tags: biztalk, filenames, biztalk-2010, send-port

In BizTalk SendPort property, I want the output filename to be appended with current datetime. Please suggest how can I achieve this.

Currently I am using %MessageID%.csv property but I want the name to be meaningfull.

ForExample: If the input file name is Test.csv, I want the output filename to be Test_29_08_2012.csv or something like that to uniquely identify the filename.

```
 <om:Element Type="Module" OID="44107b43-7a62-4452-b6a7-4fbf2fb6608f" LowerBound="1.1" HigherBound="105.1">

        <om:Element Type="PortType" OID="1b19ad0b-d962-4d86-806d-37a2176334dc" ParentLink="Module_PortType" LowerBound="19.1" HigherBound="26.1">
            <om:Property Name="Synchronous" Value="False" />
            <om:Property Name="TypeModifier" Value="Internal" />
            <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
            <om:Property Name="Name" Value="Port_ReceiveFlatFile" />
            <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="True" />
            <om:Element Type="OperationDeclaration" OID="440beff9-5144-452e-ae02-5f3f4ac2dc22" ParentLink="PortType_OperationDeclaration" LowerBound="21.1" HigherBound="25.1">
                <om:Property Name="OperationType" Value="OneWay" />
                <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                <om:Property Name="Name" Value="Operation_1" />
                <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="False" />
                <om:Element Type="MessageRef" OID="02d08019-d0c1-4d18-a00b-fc2bc1dcdb91" ParentLink="OperationDeclaration_RequestMessageRef" LowerBound="23.13" HigherBound="23.28">
                    <om:Property Name="Ref" Value="BulkUpload.FlatFileSchema1" />
                    <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                    <om:Property Name="Name" Value="Request" />
                    <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="True" />
                </om:Element>
            </om:Element>
        </om:Element>
        <om:Element Type="PortType" OID="cb4117d3-0601-4008-97db-a6c6dcfc8a75" ParentLink="Module_PortType" LowerBound="26.1" HigherBound="33.1">
            <om:Property Name="Synchronous" Value="True" />
            <om:Property Name="TypeModifier" Value="Internal" />
            <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
            <om:Property Name="Name" Value="Port_CallSP" />
            <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="True" />
            <om:Element Type="OperationDeclaration" OID="205a8265-e483-4840-b01a-67b2f79b29fa" ParentLink="PortType_OperationDeclaration" LowerBound="28.1" HigherBound="32.1">
                <om:Property Name="OperationType" Value="RequestResponse" />
                <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                <om:Property Name="Name" Value="Operation_1" />
                <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="False" />
                <om:Element Type="MessageRef" OID="87a40965-030d-47e0-b3f5-e539e05b8f86" ParentLink="OperationDeclaration_RequestMessageRef" LowerBound="30.13" HigherBound="30.41">
                    <om:Property Name="Ref" Value="BulkUpload.SQLService.BulkUploadRequest" />
                    <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                    <om:Property Name="Name" Value="Request" />
                    <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="True" />
                </om:Element>
                <om:Element Type="MessageRef" OID="4ce02fef-cd67-408c-9cf5-0e55e5b54f03" ParentLink="OperationDeclaration_ResponseMessageRef" LowerBound="30.43" HigherBound="30.72">
                    <om:Property Name="Ref" Value="BulkUpload.SQLService.BulkUploadResponse" />
                    <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                    <om:Property Name="Name" Value="Response" />
                    <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="True" />
                </om:Element>
            </om:Element>
        </om:Element>
        <om:Element Type="PortType" OID="6d8d9a28-9c62-4869-8aa9-dcc68c03ee10" ParentLink="Module_PortType" LowerBound="33.1" HigherBound="40.1">
            <om:Property Name="Synchronous" Value="False" />
            <om:Property Name="TypeModifier" Value="Internal" />
            <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
            <om:Property Name="Name" Value="Port_SendResponce" />
            <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="True" />
            <om:Element Type="OperationDeclaration" OID="8c13188d-6f2f-47ff-869c-67615b55d725" ParentLink="PortType_OperationDeclaration" LowerBound="35.1" HigherBound="39.1">
                <om:Property Name="OperationType" Value="OneWay" />
                <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                <om:Property Name="Name" Value="Operation_1" />
                <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="False" />
                <om:Element Type="MessageRef" OID="21cc1037-5a01-425f-b9d8-ab986a1e900f" ParentLink="OperationDeclaration_RequestMessageRef" LowerBound="37.13" HigherBound="37.34">
                    <om:Property Name="Ref" Value="BulkUpload.FlatFileSchema_Output" />
                    <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                    <om:Property Name="Name" Value="Request" />
                    <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="True" />
                </om:Element>
            </om:Element>
        </om:Element>
        <om:Element Type="PortType" OID="db0090d2-469b-4336-a84a-fb80eb73699a" ParentLink="Module_PortType" LowerBound="40.1" HigherBound="47.1">
            <om:Property Name="Synchronous" Value="False" />
            <om:Property Name="TypeModifier" Value="Internal" />
            <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
            <om:Property Name="Name" Value="PortType_ReplyFromSP" />
            <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="False" />
            <om:Element Type="OperationDeclaration" OID="3b0d7f64-b5f4-4a5d-95c0-7a70365ea89a" ParentLink="PortType_OperationDeclaration" LowerBound="42.1" HigherBound="46.1">
                <om:Property Name="OperationType" Value="OneWay" />
                <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                <om:Property Name="Name" Value="Operation_1" />
                <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="False" />
                <om:Element Type="MessageRef" OID="6a19b2ef-8754-4c29-8809-bb67a167d98d" ParentLink="OperationDeclaration_RequestMessageRef" LowerBound="44.13" HigherBound="44.42">
                    <om:Property Name="Ref" Value="BulkUpload.SQLService.BulkUploadResponse" />
                    <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                    <om:Property Name="Name" Value="Request" />
                    <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="True" />
                </om:Element>
            </om:Element>
        </om:Element>
        <om:Element Type="PortType" OID="6d2ec7cf-e4e6-459d-9c72-ebe9f23bd734" ParentLink="Module_PortType" LowerBound="47.1" HigherBound="54.1">
            <om:Property Name="Synchronous" Value="False" />
            <om:Property Name="TypeModifier" Value="Internal" />
            <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
            <om:Property Name="Name" Value="PortType_1" />
            <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="False" />
            <om:Element Type="OperationDeclaration" OID="63959541-c722-4478-a95e-4ecf42f6600e" ParentLink="PortType_OperationDeclaration" LowerBound="49.1" HigherBound="53.1">
                <om:Property Name="OperationType" Value="OneWay" />
                <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                <om:Property Name="Name" Value="Operation_1" />
                <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="False" />
                <om:Element Type="MessageRef" OID="07b848b3-39f0-4719-b0eb-658e3de39d4e" ParentLink="OperationDeclaration_RequestMessageRef" LowerBound="51.13" HigherBound="51.42">
                    <om:Property Name="Ref" Value="BulkUpload.SQLService.BulkUploadResponse" />
                    <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                    <om:Property Name="Name" Value="Request" />
                    <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="True" />
                </om:Element>
            </om:Element>
        </om:Element>
        <om:Element Type="MessageDeclaration" OID="fcf5f62f-fb1d-4885-a42b-fccc9ecbdeb0" ParentLink="ServiceDeclaration_MessageDeclaration" LowerBound="68.1" HigherBound="69.1">
                <om:Property Name="Type" Value="BulkUpload.FlatFileSchema_Output" />
                <om:Property Name="ParamDirection" Value="In" />
                <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                <om:Property Name="Name" Value="SendAssetDetails" />
                <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="True" />
            </om:Element>
            <om:Element Type="ServiceBody" OID="7bb1d19d-18bd-4268-8505-baabfd0e5ded" ParentLink="ServiceDeclaration_ServiceBody">
                <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="False" />
                <om:Element Type="Receive" OID="94540c63-9c2c-4963-a229-21ab2be324cf" ParentLink="ServiceBody_Statement" LowerBound="72.1" HigherBound="75.1">
                    <om:Property Name="Activate" Value="True" />
                    <om:Property Name="PortName" Value="Receive_FlatFile" />
                    <om:Property Name="MessageName" Value="ReceiveAssetDetails" />
                    <om:Property Name="OperationName" Value="Operation_1" />
                    <om:Property Name="OperationMessageName" Value="Request" />
                    <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                    <om:Property Name="Name" Value="Receive_1" />
                    <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="True" />
                </om:Element>
                <om:Element Type="Construct" OID="29f06329-5666-452f-883d-f93039631eb9" ParentLink="ServiceBody_Statement" LowerBound="75.1" HigherBound="81.1">
                    <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                    <om:Property Name="Name" Value="ConstructMessage_1" />
                    <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="True" />
                    <om:Element Type="Transform" OID="342dd643-6c41-4caa-91a8-8449cb1ab24f" ParentLink="ComplexStatement_Statement" LowerBound="78.1" HigherBound="80.1">
                        <om:Property Name="ClassName" Value="BulkUpload.Transform_ReqToSP" />
                        <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                        <om:Property Name="Name" Value="Transform_1" />
                        <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="False" />
                        <om:Element Type="MessagePartRef" OID="df2a5cfc-5cda-4f65-aef2-95dd5b3bb9e5" ParentLink="Transform_InputMessagePartRef" LowerBound="79.73" HigherBound="79.92">
                            <om:Property Name="MessageRef" Value="ReceiveAssetDetails" />
                            <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                            <om:Property Name="Name" Value="MessagePartReference_1" />
                            <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="False" />
                        </om:Element>
                        <om:Element Type="MessagePartRef" OID="2b1493eb-77e1-477a-ba81-b2143a3f0bfd" ParentLink="Transform_OutputMessagePartRef" LowerBound="79.28" HigherBound="79.39">
                            <om:Property Name="MessageRef" Value="RequestToSP" />
                            <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                            <om:Property Name="Name" Value="MessagePartReference_2" />
                            <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="False" />
                        </om:Element>
                    </om:Element>
                    <om:Element Type="MessageRef" OID="48ab8cba-8079-400e-ad45-493ab16116f7" ParentLink="Construct_MessageRef" LowerBound="76.23" HigherBound="76.34">
                        <om:Property Name="Ref" Value="RequestToSP" />
                        <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                        <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="False" />
                    </om:Element>
                </om:Element>
                <om:Element Type="Send" OID="3cf55830-5d5a-4db9-bcc0-ad807e5381b4" ParentLink="ServiceBody_Statement" LowerBound="81.1" HigherBound="83.1">
                    <om:Property Name="PortName" Value="CallSP" />
                    <om:Property Name="MessageName" Value="RequestToSP" />
                    <om:Property Name="OperationName" Value="Operation_1" />
                    <om:Property Name="OperationMessageName" Value="Request" />
                    <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                    <om:Property Name="Name" Value="Send_1" />
                    <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="True" />
                </om:Element>
                <om:Element Type="Receive" OID="aa834a70-ebc3-41a6-b138-b5c0924a4387" ParentLink="ServiceBody_Statement" LowerBound="83.1" HigherBound="85.1">
                    <om:Property Name="Activate" Value="False" />
                    <om:Property Name="PortName" Value="CallSP" />
                    <om:Property Name="MessageName" Value="ResponceFromSP" />
                    <om:Property Name="OperationName" Value="Operation_1" />
                    <om:Property Name="OperationMessageName" Value="Response" />
                    <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                    <om:Property Name="Name" Value="Receive_2" />
                    <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="True" />
                </om:Element>
                <om:Element Type="Send" OID="5cc7ab65-e76e-436e-a645-193f93afb946" ParentLink="ServiceBody_Statement" LowerBound="85.1" HigherBound="87.1">
                    <om:Property Name="PortName" Value="ResponseFromSP" />
                    <om:Property Name="MessageName" Value="ResponceFromSP" />
                    <om:Property Name="OperationName" Value="Operation_1" />
                    <om:Property Name="OperationMessageName" Value="Request" />
                    <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                    <om:Property Name="Name" Value="Send_3" />
                    <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="True" />
                </om:Element>
                <om:Element Type="Construct" OID="64d9b759-f4c2-4e84-b440-7cffcc651ac9" ParentLink="ServiceBody_Statement" LowerBound="87.1" HigherBound="93.1">
                    <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                    <om:Property Name="Name" Value="ConstructMessage_2" />
                    <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="True" />
                    <om:Element Type="Transform" OID="9112ed74-2de2-4c76-ab89-ad46f9539877" ParentLink="ComplexStatement_Statement" LowerBound="90.1" HigherBound="92.1">
                        <om:Property Name="ClassName" Value="BulkUpload.Transform_CreateSVCFile" />
                        <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                        <om:Property Name="Name" Value="Transform_2" />
                        <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="False" />
                        <om:Element Type="MessagePartRef" OID="f1fdbe31-e934-4c33-b907-31560d0da5db" ParentLink="Transform_InputMessagePartRef" LowerBound="91.84" HigherBound="91.98">
                            <om:Property Name="MessageRef" Value="ResponceFromSP" />
                            <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                            <om:Property Name="Name" Value="MessagePartReference_3" />
                            <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="False" />
                        </om:Element>
                        <om:Element Type="MessagePartRef" OID="2dc6f8d0-6265-4c60-94b1-b9fdb8272e13" ParentLink="Transform_OutputMessagePartRef" LowerBound="91.28" HigherBound="91.44">
                            <om:Property Name="MessageRef" Value="SendAssetDetails" />
                            <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                            <om:Property Name="Name" Value="MessagePartReference_4" />
                            <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="False" />
                        </om:Element>
                    </om:Element>
                    <om:Element Type="MessageRef" OID="1e6cfb87-b294-4673-bcdc-2b335edc6f65" ParentLink="Construct_MessageRef" LowerBound="88.23" HigherBound="88.39">
                        <om:Property Name="Ref" Value="SendAssetDetails" />
                        <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                        <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="False" />
                    </om:Element>
                </om:Element>
                <om:Element Type="Decision" OID="b8b4ca28-d5bb-40e1-b3ac-ead4d3e8a39d" ParentLink="ServiceBody_Statement" LowerBound="93.1" HigherBound="102.1">
                    <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                    <om:Property Name="Name" Value="Decide_1" />
                    <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="False" />
                    <om:Element Type="DecisionBranch" OID="a11c2ba8-a463-42e6-8054-b5b9e3a2e760" ParentLink="ReallyComplexStatement_Branch" LowerBound="94.13" HigherBound="97.1">
                        <om:Property Name="Expression" Value="SubscriberInformation == &quot;&quot;" />
                        <om:Property Name="IsGhostBranch" Value="True" />
                        <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                        <om:Property Name="Name" Value="Rule_1" />
                        <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="True" />
                    </om:Element>
                    <om:Element Type="DecisionBranch" OID="1c552883-30c9-4111-b6d2-4441926b2ea6" ParentLink="ReallyComplexStatement_Branch">
                        <om:Property Name="IsGhostBranch" Value="True" />
                        <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                        <om:Property Name="Name" Value="Else" />
                        <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="False" />
                        <om:Element Type="Send" OID="34517dd3-b5af-46d2-b4d0-c95d7a6d2edf" ParentLink="ComplexStatement_Statement" LowerBound="99.1" HigherBound="101.1">
                            <om:Property Name="PortName" Value="SendResponce" />
                            <om:Property Name="MessageName" Value="SendAssetDetails" />
                            <om:Property Name="OperationName" Value="Operation_1" />
                            <om:Property Name="OperationMessageName" Value="Request" />
                            <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                            <om:Property Name="Name" Value="Send_2" />
                            <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="True" />
                        </om:Element>
                    </om:Element>
                </om:Element>
            </om:Element>
            <om:Element Type="PortDeclaration" OID="f89cfd41-275c-4c18-834c-18b98a26a883" ParentLink="ServiceDeclaration_PortDeclaration" LowerBound="57.1" HigherBound="59.1">
                <om:Property Name="PortModifier" Value="Implements" />
                <om:Property Name="Orientation" Value="Left" />
                <om:Property Name="PortIndex" Value="-1" />
                <om:Property Name="IsWebPort" Value="False" />
                <om:Property Name="OrderedDelivery" Value="False" />
                <om:Property Name="DeliveryNotification" Value="None" />
                <om:Property Name="Type" Value="BulkUpload.Port_ReceiveFlatFile" />
                <om:Property Name="ParamDirection" Value="In" />
                <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                <om:Property Name="Name" Value="Receive_FlatFile" />
                <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="True" />
                <om:Element Type="PhysicalBindingAttribute" OID="d7e1285d-9cce-4c97-a861-fc517ec46266" ParentLink="PortDeclaration_CLRAttribute" LowerBound="57.1" HigherBound="58.1">
                    <om:Property Name="InPipeline" Value="BulkUpload.CsvReceivePipeline" />
                    <om:Property Name="OutPipeline" Value="Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines.XMLTransmit" />
                    <om:Property Name="TransportType" Value="FILE" />
                    <om:Property Name="URI" Value="C:\Mayur\BulkUpload\BulkUpload_IN\*.csv" />
                    <om:Property Name="IsDynamic" Value="False" />
                    <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="False" />
                </om:Element>
            </om:Element>
            <om:Element Type="PortDeclaration" OID="ab491535-5d21-4c5a-a42b-2a538c1c6886" ParentLink="ServiceDeclaration_PortDeclaration" LowerBound="59.1" HigherBound="61.1">
                <om:Property Name="PortModifier" Value="Uses" />
                <om:Property Name="Orientation" Value="Right" />
                <om:Property Name="PortIndex" Value="-1" />
                <om:Property Name="IsWebPort" Value="False" />
                <om:Property Name="OrderedDelivery" Value="False" />
                <om:Property Name="DeliveryNotification" Value="None" />
                <om:Property Name="Type" Value="BulkUpload.Port_CallSP" />
                <om:Property Name="ParamDirection" Value="In" />
                <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                <om:Property Name="Name" Value="CallSP" />
                <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="True" />
                <om:Element Type="LogicalBindingAttribute" OID="58f85bf1-f7e8-4698-86e1-42ce700829f0" ParentLink="PortDeclaration_CLRAttribute" LowerBound="59.1" HigherBound="60.1">
                    <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="False" />
                </om:Element>
            </om:Element>
            <om:Element Type="PortDeclaration" OID="f5ed8551-d0e4-4339-84c9-cd7581d1fe09" ParentLink="ServiceDeclaration_PortDeclaration" LowerBound="61.1" HigherBound="63.1">
                <om:Property Name="PortModifier" Value="Uses" />
                <om:Property Name="Orientation" Value="Right" />
                <om:Property Name="PortIndex" Value="-1" />
                <om:Property Name="IsWebPort" Value="False" />
                <om:Property Name="OrderedDelivery" Value="False" />
                <om:Property Name="DeliveryNotification" Value="None" />
                <om:Property Name="Type" Value="BulkUpload.Port_SendResponce" />
                <om:Property Name="ParamDirection" Value="In" />
                <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                <om:Property Name="Name" Value="SendResponce" />
                <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="True" />
                <om:Element Type="PhysicalBindingAttribute" OID="d54e1294-e0ab-49d9-a0af-f9bf64a17ce9" ParentLink="PortDeclaration_CLRAttribute" LowerBound="61.1" HigherBound="62.1">
                    <om:Property Name="InPipeline" Value="Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines.XMLReceive" />
                    <om:Property Name="OutPipeline" Value="BulkUpload.XmlSendPipeline" />
                    <om:Property Name="TransportType" Value="FILE" />
                    <om:Property Name="URI" Value="C:\Mayur\BulkUpload\BulkUpload_OUT\%MessageID%.csv" />
                    <om:Property Name="IsDynamic" Value="False" />
                    <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="False" />
                </om:Element>
            </om:Element>
            <om:Element Type="PortDeclaration" OID="cf4736b1-c841-447e-9e90-9f82a84c7696" ParentLink="ServiceDeclaration_PortDeclaration" LowerBound="63.1" HigherBound="65.1">
                <om:Property Name="PortModifier" Value="Uses" />
                <om:Property Name="Orientation" Value="Left" />
                <om:Property Name="PortIndex" Value="-1" />
                <om:Property Name="IsWebPort" Value="False" />
                <om:Property Name="OrderedDelivery" Value="False" />
                <om:Property Name="DeliveryNotification" Value="None" />
                <om:Property Name="Type" Value="BulkUpload.PortType_ReplyFromSP" />
                <om:Property Name="ParamDirection" Value="In" />
                <om:Property Name="ReportToAnalyst" Value="True" />
                <om:Property Name="Name" Value="ResponseFromSP" />
                <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="True" />
                <om:Element Type="PhysicalBindingAttribute" OID="9ef09822-1743-4a15-8042-37d503162a99" ParentLink="PortDeclaration_CLRAttribute" LowerBound="63.1" HigherBound="64.1">
                    <om:Property Name="InPipeline" Value="Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines.XMLReceive" />
                    <om:Property Name="OutPipeline" Value="Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines.XMLTransmit" />
                    <om:Property Name="TransportType" Value="FILE" />
                    <om:Property Name="URI" Value="C:\Mayur\BulkUpload\Test\%MessageId%.xml" />
                    <om:Property Name="IsDynamic" Value="False" />
                    <om:Property Name="Signal" Value="False" />
                </om:Element>
            </om:Element>
        </om:Element>
    </om:Element>
</om:MetaModel>
#endif // __DESIGNER_DATA
[Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.BPELExportable(false)]
module BulkUpload
{
    internal messagetype procedureRequest
    {
        body SQLService.BulkUploadRequest parameters;
    };
    internal messagetype procedureResponse
    {
        body SQLService.BulkUploadResponse parameters;
    };
    internal porttype SQLServiceExec
    {
        requestresponse procedure
        {
            procedureRequest, procedureResponse
        };
    };
    internal porttype Port_ReceiveFlatFile
    {
        oneway Operation_1
        {
            FlatFileSchema1
        };
    };
    internal porttype Port_CallSP
    {
        requestresponse Operation_1
        {
            SQLService.BulkUploadRequest, SQLService.BulkUploadResponse
        };
    };
    internal porttype Port_SendResponce
    {
        oneway Operation_1
        {
            FlatFileSchema_Output
        };
    };
    internal porttype PortType_ReplyFromSP
    {
        oneway Operation_1
        {
            SQLService.BulkUploadResponse
        };
    };
    internal porttype PortType_1
    {
        oneway Operation_1
        {
            SQLService.BulkUploadResponse
        };
    };
    [Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.BPELExportable(false)]
    internal service Orchestration_1
    {
        [Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.PhysicalBinding("FILE", "C:\\Mayur\\BulkUpload\\BulkUpload_IN\\*.csv", typeof(BulkUpload.CsvReceivePipeline))]
        port implements Port_ReceiveFlatFile Receive_FlatFile;
        [Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.LogicalBinding()]
        port uses Port_CallSP CallSP;
        [Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.PhysicalBinding("FILE", "C:\\Mayur\\BulkUpload\\BulkUpload_OUT\\%MessageID%.csv", typeof(BulkUpload.XmlSendPipeline))]
        port uses Port_SendResponce SendResponce;
        [Microsoft.XLANGs.BaseTypes.PhysicalBinding("FILE", "C:\\Mayur\\BulkUpload\\Test\\%MessageId%.xml", typeof(Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines.XMLTransmit))]
        port uses PortType_ReplyFromSP ResponseFromSP;
        message FlatFileSchema1 ReceiveAssetDetails;
        message SQLService.BulkUploadRequest RequestToSP;
        message SQLService.BulkUploadResponse ResponceFromSP;
        message FlatFileSchema_Output SendAssetDetails;
        System.String SubscriberInformation;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can do something like that  on the send file adapter file name property
`test_%datetime%.csv`
check this link [file adapter macros](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13449/Using-the-SourceFileName-Macro-to-Create-a-Custom)

**another** option  is tho set the file-name in the orchestration you can an example in the same link ,if you use port to port you can use only the first option

Comment: Is there any way to get the Source File name also instead of the hardcoded "test" that We used in the example?? I have used %SourceFileName%_%datetime%.csv but its not working :-(

Comment: can you try %SourceFileName%+%datetime%.csv 
OR 
 %SourceFileName%+_%datetime%.csv
im out of the office and cant check it myself

Comment: Hi MlkCode, I tried using %SourceFileName% alone, but its also not working. Do I need to set %SourceFileName% somewhere?? Am I missing something??

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your file adapter configuration ,
i will be able to test it myself only on Sunday i don't have biztalk at home :)

Comment: @MlkCode - Sorry couldn't upload the file earlier... uploading the odx file contents now..

Comment: @MayurJ did you figure it out ??

Answer (score 0):

What Type of Recieve Adapter are you using?

Is it file/FTP because `%SourceFileName%` Macro only works if you are using File/FTP adapter.

As these adapters can promote FileNames also make sure that you are using XML pipeline on Receive side.

Comment: @Zoltan - Yes I am using File/FTP adapter but I am using Custom Pipeline for readign CSV File. I am using a flatfile dissassembler.